# Create login page and get informations from SQL Server -> Security -> Logins

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, authentication

I have just finished developing an ASP.NET application. The only thing it needs is a login page, so you only can acces to website if you are logged in.

The database I'm connected to, has a long list of users inside `Security -> Logins`. I would like to use that list of users, to login in to my page. I can access these informations through SQL Server Object Explorer.

My question is: where do I start? Is there some places I should read about this before I start? Is there a guide which is based on the same problem like mine? All the guides I have found haven't been useful to my situation.

If my question is unclear feel free to ask!

Hope somebody can help.

**EDIT**: what I'm trying is not the appropriate way to do it. Will you recommend that I create a new "User"-table which can contain user informations? And is there a nice way I can use Entity Framework to help me create the login scene to my existing project?

**EDIT EDIT**: what I want to do is to create a login scene with a existing SQL Server database

Comment: Those are logins for the database itself, do not use them as logins for the website unless you want your database hacked. It's been a long time since I've written anything in asp.net but I beleive asp.net has a built in module for website logins.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100 %  sure if i have understood your question exactly  , But here is the steps to achieve so :

1. Store  SQL  login in your  X DB  and  Y  table
2. Connect  ASp.net  application to X DB
3. Fetch the Names in Y table and display it

To automate the process,  schedule a job in Sql Server to automatically update your Y table on daily or hourly basis.